# Why is my model so accurate when using knn(), where k=1?

Tags: r, plotly, r-caret, knn

I am currently using genomic expression levels, age, and smoking intensity levels to predict the number of days Lung Cancer Patients have to live. I have a small amount of data; 173 patients and 20,438 variables, including gene expression levels (which make up for 20,436). I have split up my data into test and training, utilizing an 80:20 ratio. There are no missing values in the data.

I am using knn() to train the model. Here is what the code looks like:

```
prediction <- knn(train = trainData, test = testData, cl = trainAnswers, k=1)
```

Nothing seems out of the ordinary until you notice that k=1. "Why is k=1?" you may ask. The reason k=1 is because when k=1, the model is the most accurate. This makes no sense to me. There are quite a few concerns:

1. I am using knn() to predict a continuous variable. I should be using something along the lines of, cox maybe.
2. The model is waaaaaaay too accurate. Here are a few examples of the test answer and the model's predictions. For the first patient, the number of days to death is 274. The model predicts 268. For the second patient, test: 1147, prediction: 1135. 3rd, test: 354, prediction: 370. 4th, test: 995, prediction 995. How is this possible? Out of the entire test data, the model was only off by and average of 9.0625 days! The median difference was 7 days, and the mode was 6 days. Here is a graph of the results:
   [Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jG9h.png).

So I guess my main question is what does knn() do, what does k represent, and how is the model so accurate when k=1? Here is my entire code (I am unable to attach the actual data):

```
# install.packages(c('caret', 'skimr', 'RANN', 'randomForest', 'fastAdaboost', 'gbm', 'xgboost', 'caretEnsemble', 'C50', 'earth'))
library(caret)

# Gather the data and store it in variables
LUAD <- read.csv('/Users/username/Documents/ClinicalData.csv')
geneData <- read.csv('/Users/username/Documents/GenomicExpressionLevelData.csv')
geneData <- data.frame(geneData)
row.names(geneData) = geneData$X
geneData <- geneData[2:514]
colNamesGeneData <- gsub(".","-",colnames(geneData),fixed = TRUE)
colnames(geneData) = colNamesGeneData

# Organize the data
# Important columns are 148 (smoking), 123 (OS Month, basically how many days old), and the gene data. And column 2 (barcode).
LUAD = data.frame(LUAD$patient, LUAD$TOBACCO_SMOKING_HISTORY_INDICATOR, LUAD$OS_MONTHS, LUAD$days_to_death)[complete.cases(data.frame(LUAD$patient, LUAD$TOBACCO_SMOKING_HISTORY_INDICATOR, LUAD$OS_MONTHS, LUAD$days_to_death)), ]
rownames(LUAD)=LUAD$LUAD.patient
LUAD <- LUAD[2:4]

# intersect(rownames(LUAD),colnames(geneData))
# ind=which(colnames(geneData)=="TCGA-778-7167-01A-11R-2066-07")
gene_expression=geneData[, rownames(LUAD)]

# Merge the two datasets to use the geneomic expression levels in your model
LUAD <- data.frame(LUAD,t(gene_expression))
LUAD.days_to_death <- LUAD[,3]
LUAD <- LUAD[,c(1:2,4:20438)]
LUAD <- data.frame(LUAD.days_to_death,LUAD)

set.seed(401)

# Number of Rows in the training data (createDataPartition(dataSet, percentForTraining, boolReturnAsList))
trainRowNum <- createDataPartition(LUAD$LUAD.days_to_death, p=0.8, list=FALSE)

# Training/Test Dataset
trainData <- LUAD[trainRowNum, ]
testData <- LUAD[-trainRowNum, ]

x = trainData[, c(2:20438)]
y = trainData$LUAD.days_to_death
v = testData[, c(2:20438)]
w = testData$LUAD.days_to_death

# Imputing missing values into the data
preProcess_missingdata_model <- preProcess(trainData, method='knnImpute')
library(RANN)
if (anyNA(trainData)) {
    trainData <- predict(preProcess_missingdata_model, newdata = trainData)
}
anyNA(trainData)

# Normalizing the data
preProcess_range_model <- preProcess(trainData, method='range')
trainData <- predict(preProcess_range_model, newdata = trainData)
trainData$LUAD.days_to_death <- y
apply(trainData[,1:20438], 2, FUN=function(x){c('min'=min(x), 'max'=max(x))})

preProcess_range_model_Test <- preProcess(testData, method='range')
testData <- predict(preProcess_range_model_Test, newdata = testData)
testData$LUAD.days_to_death <- w
apply(testData[,1:20438], 2, FUN=function(v){c('min'=min(v), 'max'=max(v))})

# To uncomment, select the text and press 'command' + 'shift' + 'c'
# set.seed(401)
# options(warn=-1)
# subsets <- c(1:10)
# ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
#                    method = "repeatedcv",
#                    repeats = 5,
#                    verbose = TRUE)
# lmProfile <- rfe(x=trainData[1:20437], y=trainAnswers,
#                  sizes = subsets,
#                  rfeControl = ctrl)
# lmProfile

trainAnswers <- trainData[,1]
testAnswers <- testData[,1]

library(class)
prediction <- knn(train = trainData, test = testData, cl = trainAnswers, k=1)

#install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)
Test_Question_Number <- c(1:32)
prediction2 <- data.frame(prediction[1:32])
prediction2 <- as.numeric(as.vector(prediction2[c(1:32),]))
data <- data.frame(Test_Question_Number, prediction2, testAnswers)
names(data) <- c("Test Question Number","Prediction","Answer")

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Test_Question_Number, y = ~prediction2, type = 'bar', name = 'Prediction') %>%
    add_trace(y = ~testAnswers, name = 'Answer') %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Days to Death'), barmode = 'group')
p
merge <- data.frame(prediction2,testAnswers)

difference <- abs((merge[,1])-(merge[,2]))
difference <- sort(difference)
meanDifference <- mean(difference)
medianDifference <- median(difference)
modeDifference <- names(table(difference))[table(difference)==max(table(difference))]
cat("Mean difference:", meanDifference, "\n")
cat("Median difference:", medianDifference, "\n")
cat("Mode difference:", modeDifference,"\n")
```

Lastly, for clarification purposes, ClinicalData.csv is the age, days to death, and smoking intensity data. The other .csv is the genomic expression data. The data above line 29 doesn't really matter, so you can just skip to the part of the code where it says "set.seed(401)".

Edit: Some samples of the data:

```
days_to_death    OS_MONTHS
121              3.98

NACC1   2001.5708   2363.8063   1419.879
NACC2   58.2948     61.8157     43.4386
NADK    706.868     1053.4424   732.1562
NADSYN1 1628.7634   912.1034    638.6471
NAE1    832.8825    793.3014    689.7123
NAF1    140.3264    165.4858    186.355
NAGA    1523.3441   1524.4619   1858.9074
NAGK    983.6809    899.869     1168.2003
NAGLU   621.3457    510.9453    1172.511
NAGPA   346.9762    257.5654    275.5533
NAGS    460.7732    107.2116    321.9763
NAIF1   217.1219    202.5108    132.3054
NAIP    101.2305    87.8942     77.261
NALCN   13.9628     36.7031     48.0809
NAMPT   3245.6584   1257.8849   5465.6387
```

Comment: Few things: 1. We can't do much with the code without any sample data. 2. It sounds like you're overfitting or working with very imbalanced data or something else that you should be checking for first. It's impossible for us to know since we don't have your data or any of the output. 3. This is better suited to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: But before anything else, I'd recommend you take a step back and learn about the k-nearest neighbors algorithm, the meaning of k, and what the algorithm is & isn't suited for. There are lots of good tutorials and books out there—I've used [ISLR](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) which has a short section on `knn`—and there should be material to learn from on Cross Validated

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be cross validation however. It does seem like I may be overfitting the data, however I am scoring high on training and testing. Overfitting is usually performing very well in training but poorly on testing. Either way, I have tested this with entirely different data and I get similar results. I guess I can share some of the data. Lemme edit my original post.

Comment: Not cross validation—Cross Validated is the statistics board on Stack Exchange. This question is better suited over there, since it isn't strictly a programming question

Comment: Alright, I will post the question over there. What should I do with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Because K = 1 is the most complex knn model. It has the most flexible decision boundary. It creates an overfit. It will perform well within the training data by poorly on a holdout set (but not always).